# What is our (Worldbuilding) Elevator Pitch

Tags: discussion

A friend was telling me in passing that she joined "the local hash," and I asked her what it was about and she said: "Great! Elevator Pitch! ..." and told very me quickly what it was all about.  I didn't have one for WP.

The idea is that in roughly the amount of time it takes in an elevator, you tell a friend or stranger everything about your group in a quick summary.  This is not the same as [What is Worldbuilding](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3341/what-is-worldbuilding), but rather:

**What is our Worldbuilding Elevator Pitch?**

**How would you describe Worldbuilding.se in 30 seconds or so?**

Comment: Hi, excellent question but it's already been asked - I merged everything over to the original :)